# Command Line: Create File Named With Date/Time

Tags: date, command-line, time, createfile

I have seen questions of these sorts listed on the site, and I've tried to work through them but haven't been successful.

What I want to do is make .bat file that creates a file (probably just a txt file, but doesn't matter) which has the Date and Time in the name.

I can use something like "TYPE File1.txt>"File2 - %DATE% - %TIME%".txt" to make the file (and without the date/time it works fine, and in fact if I change the regional settings to use - or . instead of /and: it works fine, but having the time on the PC with : is really annoying).

So I've tried the following which I got from other questions / the internet, and a few other things, but they don't seem to change the format for the date/time

```
M:\>FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %%A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B
%%A was unexpected at this time.

M:\>FOR /F "TOKENS=1* DELIMS= " %A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET CDATE=%%B

M:\>SET CDATE=%20/03/2012

M:\>FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ " %A IN ('DATE/T') DO SET mm=%%B

M:\>SET mm=%20

M:\>FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/" %A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET dd=%%B

M:\>SET dd=%03

M:\>FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %A IN ('echo %CDATE%') DO SET yyyy=%%B

M:\>SET yyyy=%2012

M:\>SET date=%mm%%dd%%yyyy%

M:\>date/t
Tue 20/03/2012

M:\>
```

As you can see, it's not working for me, even when I just call on the date I can see it's wrong...

How can I get this working?

(To be clear, the end product I want is a shortcut that if clicked at 8:13am on March 20 would makes a file "20120320 0813.txt". Or something very close)

(FYI I'm on a corporate PC running XP)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Well, I've gotten around this problem by adding a regedit to the batch.  I just change the regional settings via a regedit to something other than slash/colon, create the file, then regedit it back to what it usually is...not the best solution, since if I ever change a regional setting in the future, this command will change it back (unless I remember to change it in the reg file).  Now I just have to add a few second pause after the first edit (I think it's too quick at the moment), but that should be easy...

Comment: Okay, never mind that didn't seem to work out after all.  The time (%time%) would never display as anything but the usual with colons.  But I finally found something that works for me:

Comment: Type NULL > "doekasp-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4% %time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,2%s%.txt"

Comment: Just have to play around with the formatting to have it the way I would like it.

Comment: I was able to solve this problem with the SuperUser question: http://superuser.com/questions/47885/windows-command-line-create-a-file-with-the-current-date-in-its-name They look like duplicates, can we mark that across sites?